# Adding extra character when reading a file in Python

Tags: python, file, if-statement

I try to check if url is equal with url_auth.

```
    short_url='short.url/001'
    url='five'
    with open("shortener_db",'r',encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for line in file:
            item,url_auth = line.split(",",1)
            if item == short_url:
                shortener(take_url())
            if url_auth == url:
                print(f"""
This url is already in use!
shortener version of this url: {item}""")
                shortener(take_url())
    with open('shortener_db','a',encoding='utf-8') as f2:
        f2.write(short_url)
        f2.write(',')
        f2.write(url)
        f2.write('\n')
```

I printed both url and url_auth length, url_auth has an extra length.I suppose, python takes \n as an extra character and url becomes != url_auth.If this is the case, how can I block this from happening or if that's not the case, how can I block this and what is the case?
this is the shortener_db file:

```
short.url/001,five
short.url/002,five
```

Comment: This code is doesn't meet the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example standard.  Also there are a lot of less then desirable techniques such as globals , opening the same file twice at the same time.  Please include all the relevant code and consider making functions that work like so: ` url_auth = shortener(take_url(short_url))` so there is explicit data contracts

Comment: I edited it and did my best now.

Answer (score 2):

solved by using `line = line.strip('\n')`